# Wifi disconnects when System process takes lot of CPU

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, cpu-usage, wifi-driver, interrupts

I have Windows 10 in my laptop. Suddenly, the `System` process is taking up more CPU and also the `System Interrupts` process starts.

[image]

When it happens, my wifi connection gets disconnected and it shows "**No wifi networks found**".

[image]

To fix the issue, I have to uninstall the wifi driver and restart the computer again. The issue gets fixed every time I do this. But, when the `System` and `System Interrupts` process takes up CPU, the same problem comes back again.

[image]

I have tried to update my wifi driver and it says that the updated one is installed.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Out of interest does the Ethernet adapter work while in this state?

Comment: @SetuKumarBasak: Try to analyze what is causes the CPU usage is so high. You can use, for example, the [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). Usually, this problem is caused by drivers and if it's so, you should try to find solution on the WiFi adapter manufacture site/forums. Just for curious, is the issue gets fixed if you `Disable` and then `Enable` the Qualcomm from the **Device Manager**?

Comment: Adding to @Jackdaw's reply: in Process Explorer you can doubleclick on the 'system' process, the 'Threads' tab shows you what's using the CPU, just sort it by that column.

Comment: @Jackdaw, Yes the issue gets fixed if I disable/enable the Qualcomm driver from the device manager

Comment: @SetuKumarBasak: So, you should use the _Process Explorer_ to determine which driver is causing the problem and ask for a solution from the equipment manufacture. By the way, check what is the problem of your **AR3011 Bluetooth Adapter** - maybe it's somehow related.

Answer (score 0):

its the wifi card. i had audio problems and some reduced performance overall. i removed the wifi card and now everything is fine, it all feels much smoother. some of the modern wifi cards are defective in some way that eats up cpu cycles and makes things jittery. now i only connect to the internet using ethernet port

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).